# Question on ratio of median renumeration in balance sheet/Question on median salary of a company/ratio of median renumeration in annual report

Tags: india, income, salary, balance-sheet, annual-report

Consider below Annual report of an company for the year 2021-22 https://on.tcs.com/Annual-Report-2022

In this report on page 89 we have data on "Ratio to median remuneration for all board members", then on page 150 we have data on "Details of the Remuneration of all the board members". Using both these data we can find the "median remuneration of the employees of the organization". But for each member the median is coming differently, what could be the reason for this? How can median used for each member be different when factors affecting the median are constant?

Example calculation is as below Member 1 :- total Renumeration as per page 150 is 250+4.5 = 254.5. The ratio Ratio to median remuneration for this member as per page 89 is 38.49, hence the median remuneration of the employees of the organization = 254.5/38.49 = 6.612107

Member 2 :- total Renumeration as per page 150 is 225+3.6 = 228.6. The ratio Ratio to median remuneration for this member as per page 89 is 34.64, hence the median remuneration of the employees of the organization = 228.6/34.64 = 6.599307

as we notice for both member 1 and member 2 the median used seems to be different.

Comment: I presume "doubt" here is used in the Indian English sense, where most other dialects of the language would use 'question".

Comment: agree its a "question"